# How can I identify and purge unecessary files

Tags: disk, disk-usage, purge, cleanup

I'm running UBUNTU 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa). I have a disk usage issue and I cant find the location or identify what is consuming my disk space using the `Disk Usage Analyzer`. I know that it's located at the `/var/log`, but I don't know the exact location.
[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: You may want to start by looking in `/var/log` and see which file(s) might be consuming gigabytes of storage space. If it’s `syslog`, find out what is complaining, because it’s important. If it’s something else, [edit] your question with the details and someone may be able to offer something specific and actionable to solve your problem 

Comment: @matigo it is indeed the `syslog.1` file that is consuming more than 600 GB..

Comment: Here is one of the errors that is showing in the log file: `Sep 21 15:10:54 userdcec update-notifier.desktop[22371]: [22371:22371:0100/000000.110853:ERROR:zygote_linux.cc(241)] Error reading message from browser: Socket operation on non-socket (88)`

Comment: seems  a google chrome problem...

Comment: I found a similar question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103137/huge-syslog-file-crashing-system

Comment: If I delete this `syslog.1` file will I have problems?

Comment: Log files that end in `.1` and `.2`, etc - these are archived log files and can be safely deleted. Back it up somewhere else if you aren't sure. It would still be good to determine why these log files are so big so you can fix the root problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check how space is distributed on a Linux system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/561605/check-how-space-is-distributed-on-a-linux-system) . Retry with `ncdu /var/log` .